# Bootstrap slider doesn't appear in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a Bootstrap slider, and it works in HTML. 
I copy paste my code to the WordPress theme underscores.

I got everything working fine in my home page except for the Bootstrap slider.
When i inspect the element it is there but it is before the navmenu...

I got my code in Js main file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000 //changes the speed
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your console for errors, most likely the issue is that Wordpress uses jQuery in [noConflict mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). Try swapping out all instances of `$` with `jQuery` or use a no-conflict wrapper as described in the link above.

Comment: thanks for the answer, its not working !! i already check all the style sheets paths and its all ok, i console.log from  the main.js file and it work, so it must be something from Html/css i think...